# Handling math equation string with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an expression that always will fit this form:

variable-25.6+thing

This is a string input by the user. I want to parse out each token, excluding the operators. I though maybe a regex would be good for this, but it is harder than I expected it to be.

I am using the javascript engine btw. Here is what I have so far.

```
/(\d+\.?\d+|\w+)(?:[\+\-\*\/])(\d+\.?\d+|\w+)/
```

This works for the following:

variable
variable+25.6
25.6

But, it fails if I expand to more than one operator:

variable+25.6+other_variable+...

I tried

```
/((\d+\.?\d+|\w+)(?:[\+\-\*\/]))+(\d+\.?\d+|\w+)/
```

so that the passive group could be repeated, however, it also matches

variable+

so I am not sure why it is matching the operator even though it is in a passive group.

**UPDATE**

variable can be any text. It is just anything that matches the \w class. So, anything that is either a decimal (with or without the .) or a word can match. Any of the four operators can be between the variables/numbers. I just don't want operators to be captures, only verify that they are there.

Comment: The `(?:)` group only differs from `()` in that it doesn't save the matched portion. It's not really "passive" in any other sense.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to split on the operators?

Comment: Can you expand a little more on what should and shouldn't match? What's valid for the `variable` and `thing` part? What isn't valid for them? At the start you said the expression always fits `variable-25.6+thing`, but later you have `variable+25.6+thing`.

Comment: I thought about splitting. Seemed kind of annoying to have to split 4 times to check for each operator. Plus I thought a regex exercise would be good.

Comment: @relynt: `Plus I thought a regex exercise would be good.`: now you have two problems!

Comment: In general, mathematical expressions are irregular, and they can't be parsed with RegularExpressions.

Comment: @Teemu Good to know. I thought maybe if they fit a fairly simple pattern it would work.

Comment: @MattBurland that is what I am learning about regex xD

Comment: @relynt I said "in general", you can hit some special cases ofcourse. Basicly splitting an expression to parts (tokens) is the first step on the way to build a math parser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)ting on those operators instead of trying to match each subpattern.

```
var r = 'variable+25.6-other_variable/21.44*44.10'.split(/[+*\/-]/);
console.log(r); //=> [ 'variable', '25.6', 'other_variable', '21.44', '44.10' ]
```

Comment: Wow, didn't realize that I could split on each character with only one call to split. This is what I'll use instead.

Comment: Yes you can specify a character or regular expression using the split syntax.